# Electrical model of a tunnel junction: resistor in parallel or series with capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, electronics

I would like to understand the electrical model for a tunnel junction (used in a single-electron transistor, for instance).

In [this](https://youtu.be/PXVnvKWn5ak?t=1032) lecture, it is said that it can be modelled with a resistor and a capacitor. But how are they arranged electrically? Is the capacitance in series or parallel with the capacitor?

I would need it to be sure to understand how to calculate the total charge of the island. From the result he gets, I would deduce the capacitor is in parallel to the resistor, but I am not sure.